# Not able to understand Verilog Code for parameterized N-bit adder

Tags: verilog

I recently got a code for parameterized n-bit adder, but i didnt understand the meaning behind the code. I know that an n-bit full adder without input carry has a half adder and N-1 full adders. Have a look at the code :

```
module nbitadder(input1,input2,sum);
parameter N=10;
input  [N-1:0] input1,input2;
output [N-1:0] sum;
   wire  carry_out;
  wire [N-1:0] carry;
   genvar i;
   generate 
   for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
     begin: generate_N_bit_Adder
              if(i==0) 
              Halfadder f(input1[0],input2[0],carry[0],sum[0]);
  
             else
             
             Fulladder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry[i-1],carry[i],sum[i]);
            
     end
  assign carry_out = carry[N-1];
   endgenerate

endmodule
```

Kindly assume the modules for half and full adders are written, here are my questions:

1. Where in this code is there port connections between module instantiations for passing the carry bits?
2. What went on in the genvar block?

The simulation worked, only when i changed the radix to signed. For unsigned, the results are ridiculously wrong.

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code, it is error prune and difficult to read now.

Comment: I am not sure if you notice this problem or not but when you add 2 input numbers of size `N`  bits the result will be represented correctly in `N+1` bits but in your case the sum result is also `N` bits which will cause results to be illogical, suggested solution is to change the `sum` output to be a `wire` and add a new output `output [N:0] final_sum` and then add the following `assign` statement `assign final_sum = {carry_out, sum}` now the final sum will have the values you expect tell me if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

`generate` blocks in verilog are used to generate multiple verilog elements in an algorithmic way. In  your case there is just a loop.

```
 generate 
   for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
```

In this loop one *HalfAdder* and `N-1` FullAdders are instantiated. It is just a generic loop with a generic `if` condition:

```
   for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
     begin: generate_N_bit_Adder
           if(i==0) 
              Halfadder f(input1[0],input2[0],carry[0],sum[0]); 
             else             
              Fulladder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry[i-1],carry[i],sum[i]); 
     end
```

The above will be roughly translated into the following:

```
Halfadder generate_N_bit_Adder[0].f(input1[0],input2[0],carry[0],sum[0]); 
Fulladder generate_N_bit_Adder[1].f(input1[1],input2[1],carry[1-1],carry[1],sum[1]);
Fulladder generate_N_bit_Adder[2].f(input1[2],input2[2],carry[2-1],carry[2],sum[2]);
Fulladder generate_N_bit_Adder[3].f(input1[3],input2[3],carry[3-1],carry[3],sum[3]);
...
```

where *generate_N_bit_Adder[i]* is takent from the `begin:` statemen of the for loop and makes instances unique by adding loop iteration number.

So, the rest shoudl be clear. Every adder gets single bits from both inputs and generate a bit of *carry* and a bit of *sum*. The full adder also gets a *carry* generated from the previous adder.

The result is a multi-bit sum and a final carry assigned to the module output heres:

```
assign carry_out = carry[N-1];
```

BTW, the above is not a part of the loop and can be outside of the generate block as well as inside.

Comment: The code doesn't work for unsigned numbers, it does work for signed numbers. Kindly tell me what to do about it.

Comment: This is a different question which you should ask separately. You will need to provide all the relevant code, including implementation of the hald/full adders, your test bench and results which you see and which you desire to see.